# Filtering MySQL results between two dates

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, inner-join, where-clause

I am using the following query to get the results which i demonstrated

```
SELECT 
b.sales_title,c.cat_name,COUNT(b.sales_id) as cnt,COUNT(DISTINCT e.comment_id) as coun
FROM tb_sale_report a 
INNER JOIN tbl_sales b on a.sales_id=b.sales_id 
INNER JOIN tb_category c on c.cat_id=b.category_id 
LEFT JOIN tb_comment e on b.sales_id=e.sales_id 
GROUP BY b.sales_title

 +------------+---------+--------+------+
| sales_title | cat_name| cnt    | coun |
+-------------+---------+--------+------+
| My Sales    |Toys     |20      |5     |
| First Sale  |Dress    |28      |1     |
|Premium      |Computer |7       |16    |
+-------------+--------+---------+------+
```

Now in the table `tb_sale_report` i am also having another field named `view_date` which will store the date in which the record id added. Now i am planning to add a filtering option to the table `tb_search_report` in which the user can search the records added in between particular dates such as a start date and an end date. How can i write the `where` condition to filter the results as per the dates specified. 
Need help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :

```
SELECT 
b.sales_title,c.cat_name,COUNT(b.sales_id) as cnt,COUNT(DISTINCT e.comment_id) as coun
FROM tb_sale_report a 
INNER JOIN tbl_sales b on a.sales_id=b.sales_id 
INNER JOIN tb_category c on c.cat_id=b.category_id 
LEFT JOIN tb_comment e on b.sales_id=e.sales_id 
where left(a.view_date,10) between 'start_date' and 'end_date';
GROUP BY b.sales_title
```

Pleae replace start_date and end_date with values

Comment: Thanks a lot. It serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try and execute this query

```
SELECT 
b.sales_title,c.cat_name,COUNT(b.sales_id) as cnt,COUNT(DISTINCT e.comment_id) as coun
FROM tb_sale_report a 
INNER JOIN tbl_sales b on a.sales_id=b.sales_id 
INNER JOIN tb_category c on c.cat_id=b.category_id 
LEFT JOIN tb_comment e on b.sales_id=e.sales_id 
WHERE b.sales_date BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date 
GROUP BY b.sales_title
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to add a WHERE clause with a BETWEEN sunclause, e.g.

```
WHERE view_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i expected a detailed explanation.

Comment: You mean you wanted me to do all the work for you? Fair enough.

Comment: Sorry if you felt like that, but i didn't meant it. I am a beginner to programming and in a self learning process, hence i expect that.

Comment: I am not put out at all. I was only joking.